# What kind of operation is this?

Tags: notation

$3\circ 7=37$

$7\circ 4=74$

$a\circ b=10*a+b$

This question came me from a mathpuzzle here.

Basicly we multiply the first number by 10 and add the second number, but would this be a operation by definition of operations?

And how can we go to:

$a\circ b\circ c=100*a+10*b+c$

Comment: Did you read the tag before using it? 'Operator' is not 'operation'.

Comment: ups, i MEANT operator ;)

Comment: No, you don't. You really meant operation, but used the wrong tag.

Comment: ok, but what would be the correct tag then?

Comment: Take a look for yourself, it will be good to know more about the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an operation called "concatenation."

By definition, an operation is a function of zero or more operands to value.

Consider what it means to take $a \circ b \circ c$,

$$a \circ b \circ c = (a \circ b) \circ c$$

So, now we have

$$a \circ b \circ c = (10a + b) \circ c$$

Apply the operation again and we have:

$$a \circ b \circ c = 10(10a + b) + c$$

Simplify and we have:

$$a \circ b \circ c = 100a + 10b + c$$

Do note that if we grouped from right-to-left instead, we would not get this result. Below is the mess you would get lost in if you grouped from right-to-left:

$$a \circ b \circ c = a \circ (b \circ c)$$
$$a \circ b \circ c = a \circ (10b + c)$$
$$a \circ b \circ c = 10a + 10b + c$$

Comment: so, in the mathpuzzle only the 4 basic operations (+,-,*,:) where allowed, therefore this wouldn't be allowed? (you had to write 1_2_3_4_5_6_7=100) also brackets where allowed, but no additional numbers

Comment: Are you saying that you wanted to leverage the concatenation operation for a math puzzle? It would help if this was included in the original question. By my own definition, there exists an operation $\triangle$ such that $1 \triangle 2 \triangle 3 \triangle 4 \triangle 5 \triangle 6 \triangle 7 = 100$. The math puzzle must have placed constraints on what operations are allowed.

Comment: nah, i don't want to, i just saw a solution which involved this concatenation, where i only wanted to know if this is even following the rules. But you are right, i should have included this in the starting post. (but it wasn't the mainpoint of the question).

Answer (score 2):

You have your answer to "what kind of operation is this?" in the definition with symbols:

$a\circ b = 10*a+b$

However, in order for the following to be true:

$a\circ b\circ c=100*a+10*b+c$

you would have to define the operation as having strictly left-to-right order, so that $a\circ b\circ c\,$ is defined as $(a\circ b)\circ c$. Note that this operation is  **not** associative; that is,

$(a\circ b)\circ c \ne a\circ (b\circ c)$

in general.

Comment: Gah! You beat me by 5 seconds! +1